# How to get a unique pattern from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
 [    '0D',
      '0A,0C',
      '0C,0A',
      '0C,0E,0D,0F',
      '0C,0D,0E,0F',
      '0B,0G',
      '0B,0F'
]
```

In this list `'0A,0C'` and `'0C,0A'`.Also `'0C,0E,0D,0F'` &
`'0C,0D,0E,0F'` are similar. How to get the unique items from a list like this. I tried `set` but I guess the functionality of `set` is a bit different.

Comment: could you share your code? you should split your list elements if you're interested in comparing the substrings.

Comment: python treats that object as a list of strings, not similiar sublists of strings. as mentioned in the previous comment, you would need to convert those strings into sublists to get your expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

´set´ is good, if you use ´split´ first:

```
l = ['0D', '0A,0C', '0C,0A', '0C,0E,0D,0F', '0C,0D,0E,0F', '0B,0G', '0B,0F']

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = ','.join(sorted(l[i].split(',')))

l = set(l)
# {'0A,0C', '0B,0F', '0B,0G', '0C,0D,0E,0F', '0D'}
```